# How to setup eclipse ide for php development with pre-existing source

Tags: php, eclipse, ide

I have been using Dreamweaver for my web development and would like to try out eclipse. I would like to keep the source files where they are now. What do I need to set for my workspace and then how do I set it to look at my existing files?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You'll want to set up a workspace in the parent directory of the folder containing that project.  Then, you'll create a new PHP project in Eclipse with the same name as the folder containing that project.  That should get you going!

For example say you have a folder called Development.  Inside that you have a folder called MyProject which contains all the subdirectories and code for your PHP project.  On startup you'll select Development for your workspace and then create a PHP project called MyProject.

Answer (score 2):

Eclipse PDT:

1: New -> Local PHP Project. Create it wherever you want (e.g your workspace).

2: Import -> File System. Select the root of your source code.

3: Click Advanced -> Create Links.

Now all source files will be edited in their current location.

Answer (score 0):

Have you setup Eclipse for PHP Developers?

http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/download.php?file=/technology/epp/downloads/release/galileo/SR2/eclipse-php-galileo-SR2-win32.zip

As far as I remember, it leaves the source files intact.

Comment: Yeah, I downloaded the one from zend.com/pdt

I just don't know how to set it up the way i want.

Comment: The Zend Studio IDE is nice and all but you'll find the Eclipse for PHP Developers flavor works pretty well and is free.  I too started out with the Zend Studio and switched over to the Eclipse for PHP Developers since I wasn't using a Zend server.  There are some nice refractoring and other features on Zend Studio that I haven't found in PHP for Dev flavor but I've learned to live without them.  Just food for thought.